# Visio 2005 Enterprise Architect installation issue

Tags: visio, enterprise-architect

My laptop is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

At my job I was given `Visio 2005 Enterprise Architect` to install. It is a file named **en_visio_enterprise_architects_2005.iso**. I unpacked it and then run the **SETUP.EXE** as an administrator. It was successfully installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Visio11` folder.

But when I open it and click on `Help --> About Microsoft Office Visio` to open **About Microsoft Office Visio** window, it is showing

> Microsoft Office Visio for Enterprise Architects (11.4301.8405)
>
> Copyright 1991-2003 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

So it is Visio 2003 and not Visio 2005. How come Visio 2005 is being installed as Visio 2003? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Visio 2005. V2003 got followed by V2007.
What you've got is a special distribution with V2003 inside.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are talking about **Office Visio for Enterprise Architects 2005 (VEA 2005) – based on Visio 2003 and included with Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite and Team Architect editions** as mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio